# can i create one reference to parent node in one activity and another reference to its child node in different activity?

Tags: android, firebase

when a user clicks on a list item(a node) , a new activity is opened which shows all the childs of that list item in firebase database but when i click on list item, the app is closing unfortunately . here is my code to display all the childs of a clicked username. please do help me with this ,thank you.

```
  friend = getIntent().getExtras().get("user_name").toString();


    setTitle(friend+"'s"+" "+"status's");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),friend,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    uploadList = new ArrayList<>();
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.statusList);
    player = new MediaPlayer();

    sDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(friend);

    sDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Upload upload = postSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);
                uploadList.add(upload);
            }
            String[] uploads = new String[uploadList.size()];

            for (int i = 0; i < uploads.length; i++) {
                uploads[i] = uploadList.get(i).getName();
            }
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, uploads);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), (CharSequence) databaseError,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
    });
```

Comment: Post error log here

Comment: What is the value of String `friend`

Comment: friend is one node in firebase DB , when it is clicked the above mentioned activity is opened and it shows all the childs of that node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have resolved it by self..
instead of these two lines of code inside onDataChange

Upload upload = postSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);
                uploadList.add(upload);

change it to..

uploadList.add(postSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class));